# Как переделать функцию удаление полей, так что бы удалялось все кроме одного поля?

Tags: javascript, html, битрикс

Есть функция которая удаляет поля для фильтра.

```js
function deleteFilter(el)
{
    BX.adminPanel.showWait(el);
    if (0 < arClearHiddenFields.length)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < arClearHiddenFields.length; index++)
        {
            if (undefined != window[arClearHiddenFields[index]])
            {
                if ('ClearForm' in window[arClearHiddenFields[index]])
                {
                    window[arClearHiddenFields[index]].ClearForm();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Как сделать удаление всех полей, кроме одного

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить еще один аргумент функции, в котором нужно указывать поле, которое необходимо сохранить:

```
function deleteFilterExceptOne(el, savedField)
{
    BX.adminPanel.showWait(el);
    if (0 < arClearHiddenFields.length)
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < arClearHiddenFields.length; index++)
        {
            if (undefined != window[arClearHiddenFields[index]])
            {
                if (savedField == arClearHiddenFields[index]) {
                    continue;
                }
                if ('ClearForm' in window[arClearHiddenFields[index]])
                {
                    window[arClearHiddenFields[index]].ClearForm();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вот это от души, спасибо) буду пробывать сейчас

Comment: Когда объявляешь свой аргумент функции `function deleteFilterExceptOne(el, $arFindFields["IBLIST_A_F_CREATED_BY)`
выдает "ошибку не верный тип блока" и выходит и админки. Я думаю что туда кроме "el" вообще ничего нельзя ставить((